# Click counter on PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, click, counter

If someone click on clickme div the counter increases in the database. Currently when the page refresh the counter increases.

```
<div class="Hello">Click Me</div>    

<?php 
$find_counts = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ad_section");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_counts)){
  $current_counts = $row['no_of_clicks'];
  $new_count = $current_counts + 1;
  $update_count = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `ad_section` SET `no_of_clicks`= $new_count");
 }
?>
```

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421159/click-counter-in-php-using-jquery

Comment: Please include something u tried to do the same.

Comment: @Sanu_012 can u tell me now where i have to edit?

Answer (score 1):

Alright... so I am going to help you understand what AJAX is in a simplified practical manner.. because once you understand AJAX.. You'll be able to solve this and many other problems.

AJAX is not a 'language' or a 'technology' .. It's just an upgrade to how browsers can interact with servers.

Earlier (before AJAX, long before AJAX), when a browser had to request data/page from the server, it had to either refresh the page or request a whole new page.. and display it on a new window.. but it had absolutely no way of doing so in the "background" .. and then updating the currently displayed HTML page without any disturbance.

This is what AJAX solves.

So now.. through Javascript or Jquery.. (same thing) .. you can send a request to a server (to any end point on any web-server) with data... and the server.. then potentially has the ability to read the data you sent, process it in any way..and return back result in the form of data ..

The data going and coming is in the format of JSON (Javascript Object Notation) ..which is nothing but a way to encode data and arrays

So you send a JSON and the server gives you a back a JSON or an error page (404, etc.. )

The magic happens now...

Your page.. after receiving back the result from the server.. still on the same function execution that had sent the request ... will be able to open up the result.. and using Javascript/Jquery/DOM Manipulation.. plug in the results to the current HTML page or take any new action.. like display an alert, redirect, animate, etc..

So this is how it works:

Imagine you got a DIV upon which a click should set data update on the server and then get result from the server and refresh itself..

```
   <div id='clickme'>People clicked ... <span id='howmany'>1</span></div>

<script>

//Not accurate code, I'm just writing from what I remember .. jquery 

$('#clickme').click(function() {
 //event captured on click on 'click me'

 var nothing = ''; //there is no data to be sent, really.. because we will be getting the update from the server on how many people have clicked it.. 
 //AJAX NOW... //sending a post request
 $.post(
 'https://mywebsite/index.php/incrementMe',
 {data:nothing},
 function(data) 
 {
   //this is the function that will receive in its data the result back from the web-server function incrementMe
  var result = JSON.parse(data); //parsing the JSON into javascript object/array

  $('#howmany').html(result['updatedInfo']); //updatedInfo is the variable within the result that was sent back from the server.. which I then.. using DOM manipulation, plug it back into the span ID

}
);
//End of AJAX request... you didn't have to refresh the page..

</script>
```

On the server.. you'd have something like this: (writing PHP YII style)

```
public function actionincrementMe()
{
  $data = json_decode($_POST['data']); //got the posted variable and decoded using a PHP function .. to get a PHP array/object
  //well in fact, you don't even need this.. because.. there is no info coming to you from the front end .. but if you had, then this is how you'd receive it.. 

 $newnumber = SQL to find out latest number + 1;

 print json_encode($newnumber); //this is the function that will just answer back the front-end with a json formated data point..which is the variable new number..which you would then have received in the javascript function.

}
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the ways is by doing it like this (only the steps i have included)
- Create a table with image id and click counter
- Implement a function on the image click or div click (if there are more images then you can use a generalized image click function 
- Inside the function use ajax to implement the count increasing functionality

Comment: I am completely new to ajax